# Есть ли готовое решение контролирования такого расположения блоков?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть ли готовое решение контролирования такого расположения блоков? При удаление блока остальные должны оставаться на месте, а при добавлении новый блока должен занимать *пустое пространство не сдвигая другие* если есть свободное место между ними, и если нет просто добавляется в конце. Сами блоки разной ширины, но одинаковой высоты. Использую Vue js. Подобный механизм есть на сайте youandme.chat. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через [гриды](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) сделать, как вариант

Comment: Ну а что мешает оставить сетку (`div.flex>div.element-wrapper>div.element`), где `.element-wrapper` фиксированной ширины, а внутренний элемент `.element` уже удалять?

Comment: Я не понимаю каким образом ваши решения сделают это "а при добавлении новый блока должен занимать пустое пространство не сдвигая другие если есть свободное место между ними , и если нет просто добавляется в конце"

Comment: Думаю если какждый блок обернуть в обертку, у которыой будет ширина и удалять контент внутри обертки, то сетка останется на месте. А вот если учитывать еще и высоту не фиксированную, то тут наверное надо будет высчитывать высоту, через js, ставит ее обертке и тогда будет все ок

Comment: Ок, а что делать, если новый блок меньше (или больше) свободной ячейки?